# Submit Form and Get Response

Tags: jquery, html, forms, post, same-origin-policy

I have a form created in HTML that posts to an external domain

```
<form method="post" action="someExternalDomain.com/submit">
```

I want to submit it with this (I can't use JQuery because of the [same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033513/why-is-post-subject-to-same-origin-policy-but-submitting-a-form-with-method)) but capture the response from the server using JQuery. How would I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't post cross-domain without CORS, and jQuery can't access the response unless it is done with `jQuery.ajax` or an iframe, both of which are limited by the same-origin policy.

Comment: @KevinB So if the server implements CORS, will ```jQuery.ajax()``` or ```jQuery.post()``` be able to circumvent the same-origin policy?

Comment: Yes, though I believe it also takes some other modifications to make it work in all versions of IE.

Comment: @KevinB OK, thanks! Leave it to IE to cause problems :)... I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied) which looks like it may help with that problem. Please post your comments as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't post cross-domain without CORS, and jQuery can't access the response unless it is done with `jQuery.ajax` or an iframe, both of which are limited by the same-origin policy.

If you do wish to implement CORS, it also takes some other modifications to make it work in all versions of IE.