# "$post" Location parameter alternative

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$.post("location_sample.php",{variable:variable},function(){
   //doing something
});
```

I tried to set the location path like "localhost:8888/myweb/data/index.php", and it won't post anything, seems that the parameter cannot read full path? it start where the current page path load,

is it possible to set location in full path, so I don't need to make two types of code due to different file location?

Comment: it doesn't look like the url is pointing to the correct file...

Comment: `localhost:8888/myweb/data/index.php` is not a full URL, it’s only a path. A full URL would include a protocol, or at least start with `//` (protocol-relative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$post` is wrong function it must be replaced with `$.post`

So the code should be

```
$.post("location_sample.php",{variable:variable},function(){
   //doing something
});
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: no, I mean, I want to set the location path in direct, so I that would be like www.abc.com/data/index.php

Comment: you could use direct path in it as well

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an external URL in the `$.post()` method because of the [same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033513/why-is-post-subject-to-same-origin-policy-but-submitting-a-form-with-method).